# Can a 16 year old move to Germany with 2 adults that aren't guardians?

Tags: paperwork, germany, legal

My little brother is 16, while I am 18 and my boyfriend is 20. We are citizens in the USA.
The three of us want to live in Germany. My mom gave us permission, but she is not coming with us, and we cannot contact my father for his permission. Is my brother able to stay with us if we do not have legal guardianship?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As this is a question about relocation, I've flagged it for migration to our sister site, [Expatriates.SE]. That said, since your brother is a minor, *someone* will need to be named his guardian. I leave it to the Expats.SE experts as to whether you can fill that role and what the process would be.

Comment: Also note that to "live in Germany", all 3 of you will most certainly need appropriate paperwork (long-term visas), the type of which depends on what you are intending to do there (study, work...).

Comment: Do you have any relation to Germany?

Comment: There is a very important piece of information missing for a specific answer. What is your justification for planing to live in Germany? (Job offer, family connection, university studies etc?)

Answer (score 2):

I get the feeling that it *may* be possible, but there are a number of things to consider.

- Under German law, the guardian has the *right and duty* to supervise a minor in accordance with the minor's age and maturity. It is acceptable for a typical 16-year-old to be in a different city or even a different country than the legal guardians. They don't have to tuck him into bed *personally*.
- The unreachable father could be a **big** problem unless the mother has sole custody under US law. Guardians are supposed to act in concert, or there may be the suspicion that one guardian is trying to deny the other guardian custody in an unlawful manner.
- With the active support of the guardians, a 16-year-old could have his own flat in Germany. Except that it isn't exactly his, the guardians have to sign much of the paperwork, starting with the lease. I don't know how practical that would be from the US, unless the mother comes over to get him settled in.
  That problem is sidestepped if you and your friend sign all those contracts, but landlords will want to know who lives permanently (more or less) in any flat you rent.
- Living with adult relatives (who are not guardians) for a couple of weeks at a time is no problem. When we a talking months or longer, he will have to register with the municipal authorities as a resident in the relative's residence. At that point child welfare agencies might ask questions.
- For that matter, he is probably required to go to school, vocational school, or an equivalent program. Full-time school is not *required* if he has been at school for 10 years, but the assumption is that if he isn't at full-time school he has an apprenticeship with vocational school days.
- Unless you have EU citizenship, you will need long-stay visa. I guess he does not qualify for a skilled jobs visa yet, but it could also be difficult to pass him as your dependent.
- On top of that there are the current COVID restrictions.

Summarized, it sounds difficult enough for **you and your friend** to immigrate in Germany. A younger not-quite-dependent relative will complicate things. I don't know your personal situation in the US, but consider asking a lawyer. If you can't afford one, you almost certainly can't afford this idea (unless you hold EU citizenship, which simplifies things greatly).

Comment: Financial support for the brother will also be questioned. Can you and your boyfriend support him? Does a backup solution exist if not? All three persons should apply for a D-Visa at a German consulate to insure that no problems arise later.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, if they *need* a visa they should put the entire scheme on hold. This is not the best time to immigrate.

Comment: Well the intention is to immigrate (**want to live**). Without the guardian present in Germany it will become complicated since the Jugendamt will become envolved. With the guardian present at a consulate Interview, it will become simpler.